# How to give permission to some specific user to access some specific templates in django

Tags: django, django-users, django-permissions

I am trying to create a Online exam portal and I have created one admin portal for that site. I have 2 types of users in my site "**Students**" and "**Teachers**". How can I restrict students from accessing the admin portal and other views of admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

In views.py in function related to your template, you can use the decorator permission_required as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('foo.access_my_view')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

You have detailed instructions on how to add and modify the permissions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/)